# Streamplot like earth.nullschool.net

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

In my opinion, the visual representation of wind or ocean currents at earth website ( 
https://earth.nullschool.net/#current/ocean/surface/currents/orthographic=-44.16,41.45,1679) are stunning and captures interest of people.

[image: Sample screenshot from earth.nullschool.net]

The sample code taken from [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/plot_streamplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-plot-streamplot-py) below shows varying width along the streamlines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = 3
Y, X = np.mgrid[-w:w:100j, -w:w:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lw = 5*speed / speed.max()
ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=0.6, color='k', linewidth=lw)
```

Is it possible to work matplotlib streamlines such that it gives the above mentioned effect such as, streamlines with fading traces at the tail. Maybe changing alpha, or color along the streamline?

I would be ok with still figures, or animation ideas are all welcome.

Comment: If you decide to implement this, you are welcome to propose it as a feature to matplotlib.